# Cannot insert a specific value in SQLite for Android

Tags: android, sqlite

In my program, I fetch some values from the server with ID's. Some of the ID's returned are 0. I am executing an insert statement where I am inserting these values. When I make a Select Query, I am not able to get the values with ID = 0. I am getting every other ID's. I cannot look at the database tables because it is encrypted. I am not sure if it is not inserting it into the database or the query is not fetching it. The SELECT query does return values with ID's != 0. It is just the values with ID = 0 which is not being returned. Any clue of what I might be doing wrong, or how can I track whats going wrong in my program?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the server IDs as an index in SQLite.

Have another column for your primary key and store the server IDs in a plain NUMERIC column.